# Internet is not working on Moto G2 Sim B

Tags: internet, motorola-moto-g2, dual-sim

I have 2 SIMs from BSNL and TataDoCoMo. Tata Sim is inserted in Sim A where Internet works very well in home and roaming. Couple of days back I purchased BSNL Sim and inserted it in Sim B but Internet did not work. After all the self  troubleshooting & help from BSNL helpline, nothing worked but when I swapped the sims, Internet worked without any hiccups on BSNL sim but stopped working on Tata SIM. Please help....................

Answer (score 0):

This is because Only Sim A has the 3G support , Sim B is not 3G supporting for Moto G2. However you can use 2G in your Sim B

Comment: I think OP said Internet not working, not internet working slowly. The last time I used my phone in 2G, I had the Internet access.